# sharepoint 2013 popup modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, popup

How can i create a popup that automatically shows when the user visit the homepage? The user also want an option to not show the popup anymore.

Here is my code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  
(function(){

 function initialize() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_current();

        OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, callback, width, height, title)
 }

     window['initialize'] = initialize;
  })();

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("initialize");
```

My new code are:

On the startpage in a script editor:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, 'sp.ui.dialog.js');

  function initialize() {

  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_current();
  var currentUser = web.get_userprofile.get_current();

  var options = {
  autoSize: true,
  title: "My Custom dialog",
  showClose: true,
  allowMaximize: true
  };

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen("/_layouts/test.aspx",options,closecallback, null);
```

On the aspx page that popup shows:

```
<html>

function mDown(){

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");  
function runCode(){
var currentUser;

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onRequestFail);

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
var account = currentUser.get_loginName();
var currentUserAccount = account.substring(account.indexOf("|") + 1);
// alert(currentUserAccount);
createCookie(account,"showPopUp",10);
readCookie(account);

//obj.style.backgroundColor="#1ec5e5";
//obj.innerHTML= currentUserAccount;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 }

 function readCookie(name) {

var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
alert(nameEQ);
return null;
  }

  function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
  alert('request failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
 }
 };
 </script>
 <body>
 <button id="myButton" onClick="mDown()">Click me!</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

How can i check if the user has the cookie on the startpage?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of function `OpenPopUpPageWithTitle`

Comment: What are we using the web for?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the custom page that you're opening in a popup, add a checkbox or button (Don't show this again), then bind click handler that creates a cookie (username, showPopup)

Inside your function,

```
function initialize() {
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_current();

  // 1. get current username 
  // 2. check if the cookie exist for current username
  // 3. You can use User Profile to store the property instead of cookie
  if(showPopup == true)
     return;
  else
     OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, callback, width, height, title)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
     //Call your function
     initialize();
   });
});
```

As suggested by Arsalan, use SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, 'sp.ui.dialog.js');

Comment: Thank you i will try to seek for answear how to work with user profiles, if you dont have any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest use cookies instead of User Profiles.

Comment: ok, how can i fire sharepoint jsom code in an event handler (on click) ?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: See my updated answear

Answer (score 1):

Use as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, 'sp.ui.dialog.js');

function initialize() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_current();

    OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, callback, width, height, title)
}
```